# How to import non-go directories (e.g: C src/) with go modules?

Tags: go, vgo, go-modules

I use https://github.com/cloudflare/golz4 which is a go interface to C code. So the `src/` directory is mandatory in the dep tree.

Most dependency management ignore those directories (without `.go` files) but leave an option to force it.

e.g: go dep has

```
# [prune]
#   unused-packages = true
```

Vgo/Go1.11 mod ignore those directories but is there an option to force import them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `go` tool only tracks C sources that are in the same directory as an imported Go package — that's a deeply-engrained assumption of the cache-invalidation algorithm.

Ideally, you should send a PR to `cloudflare/golz4` to put the C sources in the same directory as the Go wrapper.